# Google Maps get LatLng on polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I'm trying to get a marker (LatLon object) for a specific distance on top of a polyline on a Google Map.

Using the `GetPointAtDistance` function of `epolys.js`, I'm getting a point on the map that seems correct, but it is a little "off" the Polyline that the map generated.

Here is an example I put together to demonstrate my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/S7VPz/2/

Preferably, I would also like to use a geodesic polyline instead of a straight one.

Comment: FYI a geodesic **is** a *curved one*.  Geodesics are segments of a great circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular polyline(geodesic line between 2 points) [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) seems to be perfect : [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/2nAgr/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/2nAgr/)